# Need help about VQMOD Positioning and Scripting

Tags: php, vqmod

I need to replace the first line of following code through VQMOD. How will I achieve it?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_store; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
```

I am currently using the following script in vqmod. But it is not working.

```
<operation>
<search position="replace" offset="1" index="1">
<![CDATA[<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_store; ?></label>]]>
</search>
<add>
<![CDATA[<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">]]>
</add>
</operation>
```

I want to replace `<div class="form-group">` by `<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">`

Also tell me what is offset and index used for? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _"Also tell me what is offset and index used for?"_ Google it

Comment: _I read it. But it is not clear._

Comment: I doubt we can explain it any better then.

Comment: _It's okay. No problem._